# ASP page migrated to new 64-bit server can't seem to access mdb-formatted user database

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, server

I have a two sites (one Classic ASP, one ASPX) housed on a 32-bit Windows 2003 server with IIS6.  I am migrating these sites to a 64-bit Windows 2008 R2 server with IIS7.5.  I've gone through all of the requisite steps to set up IIS on the new server and copied over all of the files from the old to the new server, including two Access databases in mdb format .  These are accessed via DSN connections, which have been recreated on the new servers.  I have confirmed IIS is set to run in 32-bit mode as well.  The ASPX site seems to be working, but I'm running into issues with the older site, used by our company's dealers to file warranty claims (it was created in 2007).

When users access this site (via a secure portal on our externally-hosted web page), accessing the ASP site via a link prompts them to enter their username and password.  These are checked by AuthentiX 6.2 against a table stored in one of the Access databases mentioned earlier, and if the user is in the database, they are taken to the site's first page.  Here, the username (shown as "Dealer Acct") is shown, along with two boxes where they are prompted to enter an email address and a serial number (which is checked against the second database).  However, when running test transactions on the new server, the user information is being left blank, and there is no provision to enter this information manually (by design I believe).  When I attempt to proceed to the next page, I get the following error:

"You have not filled in one of the required fields correctly.  Please correct RED colored items."

The red colored item, of course, is the username/"Dealer Account".  I did notice several 10016 error messages, leading me to believe there may be an authentication issue I'm missing based on Googling that event ID (text details of event below) 
    >

> Log Name:      System

```
> Source:        Microsoft-Windows-DistributedCOM Date:         
> 5/26/2015 11:05:33 AM Event ID:      10016 Task Category: None Level: 
> Error Keywords:      Classic User:          IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool
> Computer:      SR204A.xxxx.COM Description: The application-specific
> permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the
> COM Server application with CLSID 
> {0C0A3666-30C9-11D0-8F20-00805F2CD064}  and APPID 
> {9209B1A6-964A-11D0-9372-00A0C9034910}  to the user IIS
> APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool SID
> (S-1-5-82-3006700770-424185619-1745488364-794895919-4004696415) from
> address LocalHost (Using LRPC). This security permission can be
> modified using the Component Services administrative tool. Event Xml:
> <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event"> 
> <System>
>     <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-DistributedCOM" Guid="{1B562E86-    B7AA-4131-BADC-B6F3A001407E}" EventSourceName="DCOM"
> />
>     <EventID Qualifiers="49152">10016</EventID>
>     <Version>0</Version>
>     <Level>2</Level>
>     <Task>0</Task>
>     <Opcode>0</Opcode>
>     <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
>     <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-05-26T15:05:33.000000000Z" />
>     <EventRecordID>9833</EventRecordID>
>     <Correlation />
>     <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
>     <Channel>System</Channel>
>     <Computer>SR204A.xxxx.COM</Computer>
>     <Security UserID="S-1-5-82-3006700770-424185619-1745488364-794895919-    4004696415"
> />   </System>   <EventData>
>     <Data Name="param1">application-specific</Data>
>     <Data Name="param2">Local</Data>
>     <Data Name="param3">Activation</Data>
>     <Data Name="param4">{0C0A3666-30C9-11D0-8F20-00805F2CD064}</Data>
>     <Data Name="param5">{9209B1A6-964A-11D0-9372-00A0C9034910}</Data>
>     <Data Name="param6">IIS APPPOOL</Data>
>     <Data Name="param7">DefaultAppPool</Data>
>     <Data Name="param8">S-1-5-82-3006700770-424185619-1745488364-    794895919-4004696415</Data>
>     <Data Name="param9">LocalHost (Using LRPC)</Data>   </EventData>         >></Event>
```

I also suspect that one of the DSN links isn't working correctly, but am unsure there.  Here is the code from that page.

```
' Find the Current User
usingAuthentiXStandard = true
if (usingAuthentiXStandard) then
Set AuthX = Server.CreateObject("AUTHXOCX.AuthXOCXCtrl.1") 
else
Set AuthX = Server.CreateObject("AUTHXISP.AuthXOCXCtrl.1") 
protectedDomain = Request.ServerVariables("LOCAL_ADDR")
AuthX.SetVirtualDomain protectedDomain, Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")
AuthX.SetVirtualDomainPassword("")
end if
currentUser =      left(UCASE(AuthX.CurrentUserName(Request.ServerVariables("LOCAL_ADDR"),     Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"), Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"))),6) 

Dim errormessage
strError = ""

if Request.Form("flag") = "1" Then

Dim rsSerialNumber, connection
Dim rowcount, SQL, sConnString
Set Connection=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rsSerialNumber=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

sConnString="DSN=warrantyreg"
Connection.Open(sConnString)

SQL = "SELECT UDFREF_28, [DATE PURCH] FROM [MAIN WARRANTY REGISTRATION DATA] WHERE UDFREF_28='"& Request.Form("txtSerialNumber")&"'"
rsSerialNumber.Open SQL,connection,3,3

rowcount=rsSerialNumber.recordcount
'response.write "The number of records is " & rowcount
if (rowcount > 0) then
    if trim(rsSerialNumber.Fields("DATE PURCH").Value) <> "" then
        strNextPage = 1
    else
        if Request("regflag") = 1 then
            strNextPage = 1
        else
            if Request("regflag") = 2 then
                strNextPage = 2
            end if
        end if
    strRegError = 1 
    end if
else
    strError = "<span class=""error"">Serial Number not found.</span>"
    strNextPage = 0
end if
' Close our recordset and connection and dispose of the objects
rsSerialNumber.Close
Set rsSerialNumber = Nothing

Connection.Close
'Set Connection = Nothing
'Check Dealer Number

Set rsDealerAccount=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 
sConnString="DSN=XXXX5;UID=xx;PWD=xxxx"
Connection.Open(sConnString)



'Check Dealer Account
'SQL = "SELECT CUSTID_23 FROM [Customer Master] WHERE CUSTID_23='"& Request("txtDealerAccount")&"'"
SQL = "SELECT CUSTID_23 FROM " & chr(34) & "Customer_Master" & chr(34) & "WHERE CUSTID_23='"& Request("txtDealerAccount")&"'"
rsDealerAccount.Open SQL,connection,3,3

rowcount=rsDealerAccount.recordcount
if (rowcount = 0) then
    strNextPage = 0
    strError2 ="<span class=""error"">Dealer Account not found.</span>"
end if

if strNextPage = 1 then
    Server.Transfer("step2.asp")
    Response.end()
end if

if strNextPage = 2 then
    Server.Transfer("regrequired.asp")
    Response.end()
end if

' Close our recordset and connection and dispose of the objects
rsDealerAccount.Close
Set rsDealerAccount = Nothing

Connection.Close
Set Connection = Nothing
```

I'm hopeful that someone here can see something that I'm missing.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added the DSNs to your new server.  Also, are you aware that Win 64 has two versions of the ODBC Administrator - a 64 bit one which you'll find in Control Panel and a 32 bit one which you can find if you navigate to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`

Comment: @John - Yes, I have added the DSNs to the new server, exactly as they were in the old server.  The DSNs were added using the 32-bit ODBC administrator, not the 64-bit one.

Comment: Are you retrieving any information from registry? 
Also 32 bit keys are stored in 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\WOW6432Node 
and not anymore in the old location.

Comment: @DanieleDavì - I found the location you referenced and all of the DSNs I entered are there.  The one difference I found was the case for the path for the Access database where the user IDs is stored (access.db) was in upper case when it should have been lower case.  I tried re-creating the DSN, and it shows correctly in the registry, but still no difference.  Is there any other registry I should be looking at?  Sorry but I'm a total noob at ASP.

Comment: Final comment - turns out the problem was related to the user authentication software being used (AuthentiX).  Even after trying on a 32-bit server the problem persisted, and it turns out AuthentiX wasn't passing the UserID correctly to the page.  I had to change this line:  currentUser =      left(UCASE(AuthX.CurrentUserName(Request.ServerVariables("LOCAL_ADDR"),     Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"), Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"))),6)   to read to HTTP_AUTHXAUTHORIZATION instead of HTTP_AUTHORIZATION.  After that the site worked correctly.